# unexpected behavior textscan matlab when skipping characters

Tags: matlab, textscan

I'm trying to skip a set # of characters in Matlab using textscan. The documentation states that `%*nc` will skip `n` characters (EVEN delimiters).

I thought the following would work:

```
str = '   0:   1/ 1    1|        ASDFASDF |   1 |   5 ';
pat = '%f: %f/%f %f|%*17c|%f | %f';
wtf = textscan(str,pat,'MultipleDelimsAsOne',true)
```

which yields:

```
{[0]}    {[1]}    {[1]}    {[1]}    {0×1 double}    {0×1 double}
```

This is not correct, the last entries should be 1 and 5.

By luck I happened to try capturing those characters rather than skipping ...

```
%Notice I removed the '*' character
pat = '%f: %f/%f %f|%17c|%f | %f'; 
wtf = textscan(str,pat,'MultipleDelimsAsOne',true)
```

which yields:

```
{[0]}    {[1]}    {[1]}    {[1]}    {'ASDFASDF |   1 | '}    {0×1 double}    {0×1 double}
```

This was completely unexpected, the returned string starts at the first non-space and consumes past where I had intended. Based on this I tried:

```
%I've increased the size and removed the bordering '|' characters 
old_pat = '%f: %f/%f %f|%*17c|%f | %f';
new_pat = '%f: %f/%f %f%*19c%f | %f';
wtf = textscan(str,new_pat,'MultipleDelimsAsOne',true)
```

which yields my targeted result:

```
{[0]}    {[1]}    {[1]}    {[1]}    {[1]}    {[5]}
```

I would have thought that after matching the literal character '|' that `%*nc` would start consuming/skipping at the space, not after the first non-space. Is this behavior expected based on the documentation? What's happening here?

Note, I originally had `%[^|]` in this area but I ran into problems when the text itself was `'|'` or `'||'`. So now I'm going to do a double pass (or maybe actually capture and then trim the whitespace) since I couldn't figure out how to adjust the `textscan` call to gracefully ignore those cases.

Comment: Why trying to count the exact numbers of characters, use the string specifier: If I try `pat = '%f:%f/%f%f|%*s|%f|%f';` I get the correct output straight away.

Comment: @Hoki The field is fixed width and could contain anything (technically not anything but I am treating it as such). If it contains `'|'` it will be escaped with single quotes. Later on I need to parse a variable content string that comes after the last '|' (after the 5 in this example), i..e `str = '   0:   1/ 1    1|        ASDFASDF |   1 |   5  | % any | thing | here`  I am surprised that your example works if I place `'|'` in the text area. I guess the rule is to parse to a delimiter, not to parse until '|'. Your example doesn't work if there is a space `ASD ASDF`

Comment: Why not just use a regular expression? Looks to me like you are using the wrong tool

Comment: @Paolo That is certainly an option but my experience has been that `textscan` is a lot more efficient when extracting a lot of numbers and rows.

Comment: Efficient in terms of speed? While that may be true, a regex is probably easier to read and maintain (given its universality).